# Java array to multi dimensional

Tags: java, arrays

Is it possible to take an array of say 100 chars and turn it into a 2d array of 10*10?

Comment: No. A *3D* array has 10*10*10 cells, making 1000 chars. You have only 100.

Comment: Are the numbers 100 and 10 x 10 meaningful or arbitrary?  I mean do you want something that works for just that case or for any case?  Your wording suggests that it is arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
char[] chars = ("01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789" + 
                "01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789")
                .toCharArray();

char[][] char2D = new char[10][10];

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    char2D[i / 10][i % 10] = chars[i];
```

Now the this code...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(char2D).replaceAll("],","],\n"));
```

...prints the following

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate throughout your list of 100 chars and divide it amongst the 10*10,
Modulus (%) will probably be very useful.

You could use 2 nested for loops to assign the chars of the array to the appropriate element.